# Why is the answer submitted wrong

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, bubble-sort, function-definition

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(char *s[],int n)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int x=0;
    int k=i;
     
       for (x=0;x<n-1;x++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
                {
                if(*(*(s+j)+i)>*(*(s+j+1)+i))
                   {
                    char *temp;
                    temp=*(s+j);
                    *(s+j)=*(s+j+1);
                    *(s+j+1)=temp;
                     }
                else
                    if(*(*(s+j)+i)==*(*(s+j+1)+i))
                    {
                      for(k=1;k<n-1;k++)
                      {
                          if(*(*(s+j)+k)>*(*(s+j+1)+k))
                       {
                          {
                              char *temp;
                              temp=*(s+j);
                              *(s+j)=*(s+j+1);
                              *(s+j+1)=temp;
                              break;
                          }
                       }
                      }
                    }
                }
        }
}
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    char * str[100];
    char a[100][100];
    while(n<=100&&gets(a[n])!=NULL)
    {
        str[n]=a[n];
        n++;
     }
    f(str,n);
    int i=0;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        puts(str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's the question of this code:Input multiple English words to the string array, in alphabetical order from small to large output and you can't use strcmp.

The sample input:
one
two
three
four

Sample output  :
four
one
three
two

My question:
What's wrong with this code

Comment: The code is just very awful.

Comment: The output appears to be correct (alphabetical order).

Comment: Do try to use more meaningful variable names so that the reader can understand your code. Also, do you mean, arrange the strings in ascending order, because the question you are asking is a bit unclear? If so, just use strcmp to get which order the strings should be and use any normal sorting algorithm

Comment: @sudafin This while loop while(n<=100&&gets(a[n])!=NULL) can invoke undefined behavior when n is equal to 100.

Comment: *Never* use `gets`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: @sudafin This for loop                      for(k=1;k<n-1;k++)
                      {
                          if(*(*(s+j)+k)>*(*(s+j+1)+k))
                       { also can invoke undefined behavior due no using the condition k < n - 1 because the length of a string can be much less than the value of n -1.

Comment: I like calling this kind of code the star wars.

Comment: The main reason why people don't like the code is the pointless re-direction and pointer arithmetic. Don't write unreadable stuff like `*(*(s+j)+i)`, write `s[i][j]`. Also don't use `gets` since it has been obsolete for several decades and was finally removed from the C language one decade ago.

Comment: Programming is not an intellectual puzzle where you try to get a program that works using the minimum or cleverest set of characters that gets the compiler to do what you want it to do.  Programming is *communication*, so a program must be *readable* by other humans.  (And, of course, it must also get the compiler to do what you want it to do.)  Why name your function `f()` when `sort()` would be so much clearer?  Why write things like `*(s+j)` when `s[j]` would be so much clearer?

Comment: @SteveSummit Famous quote: “Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" - Brian Kernighan

Comment: I printed this and put it on my fridge, thanks

Comment: Regarding your function,  `void f(char *s[], int n)` is wrong. `void f(char *s, int n)`, `void f(char s[], int n)`  both are correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For starters declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used. That is instead of this code snippet

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int x=0;
int k=i;
 
   for (x=0;x<n-1;x++)
   //...
```

You could just write

```
   for ( int x=0;x<n-1;x++)
```

Otherwise the code is difficult to read. For example this initialization

```
int k=i;
```

says nothing for the reader of the code because the variable k is overwritten in this for loop

```
for(k=1;k<n-1;k++)
```

You need not to separate comparisons of first characters of strings and next characters of strings in case when the first characters are equal. Such a separation again just confuses readers of the code. Instead you could use the standard function `strcmp` to compare two string.

This for loop

```
                  for(k=1;k<n-1;k++)
                  {
                      if(*(*(s+j)+k)>*(*(s+j+1)+k))
                   {
                      {
                          char *temp;
                          temp=*(s+j);
                          *(s+j)=*(s+j+1);
                          *(s+j+1)=temp;
                          break;
                      }
                   }
                  }
```

can invoke undefined behavior because length of the compared strings can be much less than the value of the expression `n-1`.

Instead of the for loop it is better to use the while loop

```
  k = 1;
  while ( *(*(s+j)+k) != '\0' && !( *(*(s+j)+k) > *(*(s+j+1)+k) ) )
  {
      ++k;
  }


  if( *(*(s+j)+k) != '\0' )
  {
      char *temp;
      temp=*(s+j);
      *(s+j)=*(s+j+1);
      *(s+j+1)=temp;
  }
```

Though it is much better to use the subscript operator instead of the dereferencing operator.

This while loop

```
while(n<=100&&gets(a[n])!=NULL)
```

can invoke undefined behavior when n is equal to 100 because the valid range for the arrays is `[0, 100 )`.

The function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. It is better to use for example fgets.

Comment: I just learned it now, so I don't understand some of it. Thank you very much for your answer. I will study it carefully.